# how to set default branch in Azure DevOps yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

This is my YAML file, as you can see, the YAML file is in the `master` branch.

When I manually queue a build, by default, it uses `master` as the branch to build.

I am wondering if I can set the default branch to `R_current_sprint`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you edit the YAML in Azure DevOps click on **Triggers**:

[image]

Then go to the **YAML** tab, click on **Get sources**, and you will see the option to choose the default branch:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put a copy of this yaml file in your other branch named R_current_Sprint. Be sure to rename all instances of `master` in the R_current_sprint branch yaml file to `R_current_sprint`.

Comment: ok, so I can't set a default branch as in the classic designer?

Comment: If an other users uses this the default branch is different. Is this solved in the yaml file?